# Not Enough Space?

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I have had my phone for about 4 months now, and have been facing this problem recently. When I download an app, it says I don't have any space, when I check my storage, I have about 472 MB left out of 3 GB on my phone. It won't let me download a 40 MB app, why? I have tried deleting all the cache and also tried restarting my phone, but nothing works. I don't want to keep getting rid of apps for new ones, I can't seem to fix this problem. So, please tell me how to fix this.

Comment: I've just added the `insufficient-storage` tag to your question. Please check [its tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) for first aid. Especially take the different storage areas into consideration for the "why": there are 2 types of "internal storage", the "internal SD card" and the device internal memory (aka "phone storage", `/data`). It's the latter one causing this error message.

Answer (score 0):

At times only a small part of a program is downloadable from the play store. After downloading the 40MB , the app will probably require to download another 400MB+. Best solution would be to download 'Cleaner Master' from the playstore. It tells you exactly how much you have remaining in your phone and provides excellent advice on where to clear some space. Hope this helps :D

Answer (score 0):

This is the typical bad behavior of android. I get the warning, if I have 600mb of 16gb left. You can try to move some big apps on your SD card, uninstall other apps. Or clean the cache in the settings > storage> clean cache.

Answer (score 0):

First install Diskinfo app from Google Play, to see how much free space do you have on your data (userdata) partition.

Then:

- first use Total Commander to detect which of your directories on the internal sdcard are occupying the most. Move them to the external sdcard. Total Commander can "Calculate occupied space" for each directory. Let me know if you need details how to do it.
- uninstall some apps
- you can clean the cache of some apps (I would first clean cache of browser apps and Facebook).
- move some apps to sdcard.
- use Link2SD app to move some apps to the external sdcard (if you create extsd partition on your sdcard, you can also move libraries & data to the sdcard, too).

If you need, I can further help you with one of these solutions to go through.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone who needs this, most Samsung devices have this secure folder stuff which takes about half of the phone's memory, you can disable it by searching "secure folder" in settings and the option to disable it should show somewhere in the screen.

And try moving some apps to SD card and don't forget to move it back to SD card again after it has been updated.

One thing i usually do before i found the secure folder stuff was this - I'd clear the data of an app that takes up a lot of space like snapchat (settings --> apps --> snapchat --> Clear data). It will log you out and free up some space. Snapchat, Instagram and Facebook takes up more space than any social app i've ever used.

Another trick is with whatsapp. Whatsapp wil automatically backup your chat to your phone by default in internal storage or phone storage  --> Whatsapp --> DataBases. This happens every 2AM. Try Clearing it everyday

Answer (score 0):

This typically happens to Samsung devices. It is because the phone has a secured folder and some hidden folders that eat memory. These folders store user specific data and take backup of the settings and so they demand some space to stay empty all the time.

But the best part is you have an SD slot, you can always move some of the photos and applications to it and keep the memory free in mobile device.